# While pushing to git using Termux, it crashes while compressing files

Tags: terminal, termux

I am pushing large number of files to git from android using Terrmux.

```
git push origin master
```

There is no issue pushing up to 40 files of around 1.5 MB. But when number of files is larger, Termux simply crashes while compressing the files.

Any Idea how can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you don't have enough free disk space for the compression.

(Termux resides in the local storage and not on the SD card, so you'd need to check your device's free space.)

Comment: This can be a network throughput issue as well.  When you state `simply crashes while compressing` do you mean git  in Termux or the Termux app?  What is the output of the crash?